# Is this correct usage for loading a zip file into memory from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am getting strange HTTP errors after I load a file from GCS in my python web app..

```
suspended generator urlfetch(context.py:1214) raised DeadlineExceededError(Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucketname]/dailyData_2014-01-11.zip)
```

However, based on what the app is logging below, it has already loaded the file (and based on memory usage, appears to be in memory).

```
bucket = '/[bucketname]'
filename = bucket + '/dailyData'+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.zip'
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,'r')
gcs_stats = gcs.stat(filename)
logging.info(gcs_stats)
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(gcs_file, 'r')
logging.info("zip file loaded")
```

Is there a way I should close the HTTP request or is it not actually loading the zip_file from memory and is instead trying to pull from GCS all the time...? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you close the files you're opening. You can use a `with` context, which will automatically close the file when it goes out of scope:

```
bucket = '/[bucketname]'
filename = bucket + '/dailyData'+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.zip'
gcs_stats = gcs.stat(filename)
logging.info(gcs_stats)
with gcs.open(filename,'r') as gcs_file:
  with zipfile.ZipFile(gcs_file, 'r') as zip_file:
    logging.info("zip file loaded")
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! Do I need to add a StringIO.StringIO line or does the zip file.ZipFile() line go ahead and read the gcs_file object?